# How to count The number of peaks to calculate the bpm using nodemcu and Arduino ide

Tags: arduino

can any one help me out on how to get the bpm from a Pulse sensor using Arduino ide and a nodemcu esp8266(12 E) .

I have this code but it is not giving the bpm but readings around 833 samples per second.

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, ...  could you possibly provide less information? what is "this code" what pulse sensor are you talking about? how are you going to solve a complex technical problem if you're not able to communicate that problem in a reasonable manner? please read [ask]. you'll find all kinds of helpful tips on how to ask a good question. if you can't proceed with the information you have, how should we help you proceed without any useful information?

Comment: You forgot to add the sample data and your code, which gives you the obviously wrong result of 833 BPM

Answer (score 0):

Definitely need some more information, but the general process is something like this:

1. Detect peaks (or valleys)
2. Store the micros() or millis() value when you detect the peak.
3. When you detect the next peak, subtract the current millis() from the previous. That's the period between the two beats in milliseconds.
4. Convert from period to BPM by dividing 60,000/period.

Comment: hi in your suggestions point 2) is where I'm stuck, not able to detect the peak. how to know when the peek occurs only then i think i will be able to find the time.

Comment: The simplest way to detect a peak is that the value went down from the previous. If you are going up a slope, you'd see something like 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2. When it goes from 5 -> 4 you passed a peak. This works when the data is smooth, but if it is noisy, you'll need to take some extra steps to make sure it wasn't just noise.